# display information about an object selected in a listbox in textboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to display the information about whichever flight is selected in the listbox in textboxes next to it. My problem is I can't get my curFlight variable to work right gives me InvalidCastException was unhandled error and says When casting froim a number, the value must be a number less than infinity.

heres my form code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Reservations
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Flight curFlight;

        Flight flight1 = new Flight("Cessna Citation X", "10:00AM", "Denver", 6, 2);
        Flight flight2 = new Flight("Piper Mirage", "10:00PM", "Kansas City", 3, 2);

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MakeReservations();
            DisplayFlights();

        }

        private void lstFlights_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            curFlight = (Flight)lstFlights.SelectedItem;
            txtDepart.Text = curFlight.DepartureTime;
            txtDestination.Text = curFlight.Destination;
        }

        private void MakeReservations()
        {
            flight1.MakeReservation("Dill", 12);
            flight1.MakeReservation("Deenda", 3);
            flight1.MakeReservation("Schmanda", 11);
            flight2.MakeReservation("Dill", 4);
            flight2.MakeReservation("Deenda", 2);
        }

        private void DisplayFlights()
        {
            lstFlights.Items.Clear();
            lstFlights.Items.Add(flight1.Plane);
            lstFlights.Items.Add(flight2.Plane);
        }

        private void btnMakeReservation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name;
            int seatNum;

            name = txtCustomerName.Text;
            seatNum = Convert.ToInt16(txtSeatNum.Text);

            curFlight.MakeReservation(name, seatNum);
        }
    }
}
```

HERES THE CLASS CODE

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Reservations
{
    class Flight
    {
        private string mPlane;
        private string mDepartureTime;
        private string mDestination;
        private int mRows;
        private int mSeats;
        private string[] mSeatChart;

        public Flight()
        {
        }

        public Flight(string planeType, string departureTime, string destination, int numRows, int numSeatsPerRow)
        {
            this.Plane = planeType;
            this.DepartureTime = departureTime;
            this.Destination = destination;
            this.Rows = numRows;
            this.Seats = numSeatsPerRow;

            // create the seat chart array
            mSeatChart = new string[Rows * Seats];

            for (int seat = 0; seat <= mSeatChart.GetUpperBound(0); seat++)
            {
                mSeatChart[seat] = "Open";
            }
        }

        public string Plane
        {
            get { return mPlane; }
            set { mPlane = value; }
        }

        public string DepartureTime
        {
            get { return mDepartureTime; }
            set { mDepartureTime = value; }
        }

        public string Destination
        {
            get { return mDestination; }
            set { mDestination = value; }
        }

        public int Rows
        {
            get { return mRows; }
            set { mRows = value; }
        }

        public int Seats
        {
            get { return mSeats; }
            set { mSeats = value; }
        }

        public string[] SeatChart
        {
            get { return mSeatChart; }
            set { mSeatChart = value; }
        }


        public void MakeReservation(string name, int seat)
        {
            if (seat <= (Rows * Seats) && mSeatChart[seat - 1] == "Open")
            {
                mSeatChart[seat - 1] = name;
            }
            else
            {
                //let calling program know it didnt work.

            }
        }

        public bool IsFull()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you step through the code in the debugger, what line raises the exception?

Comment: curFlight = (Flight)lstFlights.SelectedItem;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer by MVCKarl is more general, I'll show an easier way, which could suit in simple cases.

You could simply override `ToString` for the `Flight` class:

```
class Flight
{
    //your code

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //or anything you want to display
        return this.Plane;
    }        
}
```

Then edit `DisplayFlights` method to add flights into the list:

```
private void DisplayFlights()
{
    lstFlights.Items.Clear();
    lstFlights.Items.Add(flight1);
    lstFlights.Items.Add(flight2);
}
```

After this your `lstFlights_SelectedIndexChanged` would start working as expected:

```
private void lstFlights_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    curFlight = (Flight)lstFlights.SelectedItem;
    textBox1.Text = curFlight.DepartureTime;
    textBox2.Text = curFlight.Destination;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect! I think this is the best solution for this simple program. We did some work like MVCKarl's example with lists and all that but the teacher said that's more than we'll need until next quarter in Advanced C#. Thanks Konstantin and MVCKarl!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are assigning a string to the listbox and then trying to cast that string to a Flight Object

```
lstFlights.Items.Add(flight1.Plane);   // Just say it is named "Plane 1"
lstFlights.Items.Add(flight2.Plane);   // Just say it is named "Plane 2"


curFlight = (Flight)lstFlights.SelectedItem; // Now you are trying to convert "Plane 2" into a flight object which is incorrect
```

Try this instead

Add a Global List of type flights

```
List<Flight> flightList = new List<Flight>();

Flight flight1 = new Flight("Cessna Citation X", "10:00AM", "Denver", 6, 2);
Flight flight2 = new Flight("Piper Mirage", "10:00PM", "Kansas City", 3, 2);
```

in your form load add SetupFlights

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        MakeReservations();
        DisplayFlights();
        SetupFlights();  // added this line
}

 private void SetupFlights()
 {
        flightList.Add(flight1);
        flightList.Add(flight2);
 }
```

and your selected Index Changed should be something like this

```
private void lstFlights_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        curFlight = flightList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Plane == lstFlights.SelectedItem.ToString()); // Changed this line
        txtDepart.Text = curFlight.DepartureTime;
        txtDestination.Text = curFlight.Destination;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to do this apparently this is the first assignment i've ever done that is object oriented and looking through the example code from class is no help. I don't even know how to say this to google to get some useful information. How do I code it to simply see which object is selected in the listbox and display the destination value and departure time value into the textboxes.

Comment: oh i hadn't seen your edit ok i'm gonna toy with that a bit and see if I can get some results. Thanks!

Comment: Put all the objects into a List (as my example has done) and then you can use LINQ to find the object you are after. You are welcome. It is all about learning the basics and then you will do well.

Comment: Yeah I am doing great in the class have an A but now were doing object oriented stuff and it's my first experience with it so it's messing me all up once I get a firmer grasp on this I think it'll be smooth sailing.

The problem i'm having now is since I moved the setup of the flights into it's own method it's messing the other methods up because the flights don't exist in their context.

Comment: the DisplayFlights() method is what i'm referring to exactly. I should display the information from the list rather then the object right.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't realise you were using the flights in the other methods. You can move the flights to be at a global level. I changed my answer to reflect that. It should work fine after that

Comment: certainly sorry I'm new to stackoverflow!

Comment: That is fine :) Welcome to SO and all the best with your programming!